# Geofence Notification not get when app is in background.

Tags: android, geofencing

I am really stuck at this point.Geofence really works fine when app is in forground that is notification comes properly. but when app goes is in background notification not comes.

I want like this when app is in background my geofence never expired and and get notified if user is outside the fence.

Also attached the code below:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap map;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg);
        return intent;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_geofence);

        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        editor = pref.edit();


        initGMaps();
        createGoogleApi();


    }


    private void initGMaps() {
        //mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        settingsrequest();

    }

    public void settingsrequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


        // googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
        getLastKnownLocation();
        //recoverGeofenceMarker();
        startGeofence();

    }

    private final int REQ_PERMISSION = 999;

    // Check for permission to access Location
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
        // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    // Asks for permission
    private void askPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQ_PERMISSION
        );
    }


    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if (checkPermission()) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
                writeLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        } else askPermission();
    }


    private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
        //textLat.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude());
        //textLong.setText("Long: " + location.getLongitude());
        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void writeLastLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
    }

    private Marker locationMarker;

    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation(" + latLng + ")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if (map != null) {
            if (locationMarker != null)
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }


    // Start Geofence creation process
    private void startGeofence() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence();
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
        addGeofence(geofenceRequest);
    }

    private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
    private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 500.0f; // in meters

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");

        //Intent i = getIntent();
        //double la = i.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        //double lo = i.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);

        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
                .setCircularRegion(18.457532, 73.867746, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
    private static final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if (geoFencePendingIntent != null)
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    request,
                    createGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
    }




    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    // Defined in mili seconds.
    // This number in extremely low, and should be used only for debug
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 900;

    // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged [" + location + "]");
        lastLocation = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {


        Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
//            saveGeofence();
            //drawGeofence();
        } else {
            // inform about fail
        }

    }


}
```

also attached Reciever code:-

```
public class GeofenceReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
    Context contextBootReceiver;
    Intent intent;
    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.contextBootReceiver = context;
        this.intent = intent;
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = pref.edit();


        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // Handling errors
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMsg);
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        // Check if the transition type is of interest
        if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            // Get the geofence that were triggered
            Log.d("Trnsition", "Exited");
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences);
            // Send notification details as a String
            //if (feedback.equalsIgnoreCase("F;1;")) {
            //  String temp = feedback;


                sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);


        }


    }


    private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        // get the ID of each geofence triggered
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }

        String status = "Some switches are on";
        if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            System.out.println(status);
        return status + TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {


        //intent = new Intent(contextBootReceiver, MainActivity.class);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //contextBootReceiver.startActivity(intent);

        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg);


        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
                contextBootReceiver, msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(contextBootReceiver);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) contextBootReceiver.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(contextBootReceiver);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Droidhomes Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }


    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Implement your code inside a service and keep it running in background that way your problem will be solved

Comment: @sumit:-How did i run service in background?did u help me with with some example code?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Write your service like this:

```
public class GeoFencingService extends Service{

@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      //write your notification code here
//use START_STICKY if you want your service keep running else use START_NOT_STICKY
      return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //use this method to communicate with your activity
    return null;
  }
}
```

for detailed explanation have a look at these two links:

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html
```

Let me know if any more help is required

Comment: so Instead of broadcaster used service?

Comment: No let it that way use service for the work you were doing in the activity and start the service from your activity. So now when your activity will go in background your service will keep running and you'll get notification

Comment: Sorry bro didn't understand.                                                             
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); like this?

Comment: see it depends on you can either do all the work of your mainactivity in your service or you can divide it also. like you can take location in your activity then pass it to your service and then from your service you can fire the broadcast using pending Intent that your Geofencing reciver will recieve and do the work

Comment: but to fire the notifications from the background your broadcasting part should be inside the service so that you can send notifications from background also

Comment: Thanks.I will try.Did u on skype so will discuss better.my skype id:-sagar.1351@gmail.com

Comment: Actually I am in office so won't be able to discuss it on Skype you can post here if you get stuck in something

Comment: ok.i will do like broadcast reciever is seprate and service is seprate so i am able  get notifications but one question oncreate method of my activity i write         startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GeofencingService.class)); this code so it will produce null value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146412/discussion-between-sumit-and-sagar-potdar).